# T-flip-flop without using a clock

Tags: flipflop

Is it possible to create a T flip-flop without using a clock? I really need one, but I can't use one with a clock because it requires a signal shortener.

Comment: How would the flip-flop know when it has to flip or flop?

Comment: I think that, by definition, a T flip-flop requires a clock.  What do you really want this flip-flop to do?

Comment: I want it to toggle when it receives a signal

Comment: It's *always* receiving a signal. Sometimes that signal is high, and sometimes it is low.

Comment: No. Usually it receives a clock signal that switches between high and low. It has another input that triggers the toggle. I need one without the clock part, but that doesn't seem like that is possible.

Comment: No, the *clock* triggers the toggle. The other input *enables* it.

Comment: If that is true then it should be possible to remove the clock. Right?

Comment: Again, **how would the flip-flop know when it has to flip or flop?**

Comment: Can you provide a timing diagram of what you need? And please explain what is a "signal shortener"? ... Synchronous logic design clocks all flip-flops with a global clock distribution system, designed to prevent clock skew. All flip flops in the system are supposed to capture at exactly the same time. So it's unclear how a flip flop could be considered useful without something driving its clock input.

Comment: The flip flop will know when it needs to flip or flop when it receives a high signal. A signal shortener is a thing that takes a signal and makes it into a pulse.

Comment: In electronics that's called a `one-shot pulse generator`; not sure why Minecraft uses a different term for the same idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just wire the toggle input to a high level and then your signal goes into the clock input, this way the output toggles as soon as there is a rising edge on the clock input.